# swift SwiftyJSON to get value

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I have a json string: `let jsonStr = {"username":"Jame"}`, and I use swiftyJson: `let json = JSON(jsonStr)`. Now I want to get the username, so I try `json["username"].string`, but the result is nil.

Comment: Is there a compile error with the code: let jsonStr = {"username":"Jame"}

Answer (score 1):

First, You should use
`let jsonStr = "{\"username\":\"Jame\"}"`
instead of
`let jsonStr = {"username":"Jame"}`

If `jsonStr` is just String, you need to convert String to Dictionary.
`JSON` initializer requires instance of Dictionary. try this:

```
let jsonStr = "{\"username\":\"Jame\"}" // string
let jsonData = jsonStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)! // string->NSData
let jsonDic = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .AllowFragments) // NSData->Dictionary
let json = JSON(jsonDic) // good!
print(json)
let name = json["username"].string
print(name) // Optional("Jame")
```

More safely, you use `if let`, `do{} catch(let e){}` instead of `!`,`try!`

Comment: I have done almost the same  to youl. But there is no the statment 'let jsonDic = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .AllowFragments) // NSData->Dictionary' , it still work fine.